# Count overflowed List items from both Left and Right side. (Not top/bottom)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have code where I want to count overflowed list items from both **Left and Right** side (not from top or bottom). In this jsfiddle. Initially 1,2,3,11 & 12 are overflowed. but I want to count with Jquery. and later when it changes it counts automatically.

In addition, would it be possible to count width of overflowed items.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dmp8zfe4/)**

```
$(document).on('click', '.liClicked', function () {
var idValue = ($(this).attr('id'));
var idValues = ($(".element ul li#" + idValue));
var me = $(this);
$('.element').animate({
    "left": $('li#' + me.prop('id')).position().left * -1,
}, 500, function () {
    var newPosition = $('.element').position().left;
    });
});
```

Comment: perhaps you want something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/y2f176Lb/

Comment: where's the code that counts the overflow items?

Comment: I didn't uploaded the because. that count all the element not overflowed.

Answer (score 0):

try this code to count elements :

```
parseInt(idValue.split('tab')[1])
```

to get width :

```
parseInt(idValue.split('tab')[1])*$('.liClicked').width()
```

here is a [demo example](http://jsfiddle.net/y2f176Lb/)